# Replace vectors in 2d numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `numpy array` of shape `(height, width, 3)` loaded from an image. I want to replace all black pixels `[0, 0, 0]` with a specific color `[r, g, b]`. Is there a `numpy` way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
orig_color = (0, 0, 0)
replacement_color = (r, g, b)

data[(data == orig_color).all(axis = -1)] = replacement_color
```